# Creating 2D points near y=x

Tags: matlab, matrix, svd

I need to generate some random 2D points (for example 30 points) near the y=x line, insert them in a matrix, plot it and then calculate the SVD of the matrix. But since I'm new to MATLAB I don't know how can I generate my desired matrix.

Comment: You need to try something before asking questions here. Have a look at the Matlab functions `rand` or `randn`. You also need to define what near means and what your domain is going to be (i.e. limits for `x`). You'll also find the `plot` and `svd` functions helpful. Please try it yourself and post some code, even if it's wrong.

Comment: oh man these people wont ever refrain @MoNo SO community isnt a sort of magical box where you put question you receive answers, noone would help you here when you dont make your first step toward

Answer (score 3):

Since this looks like homework I'll just post some general ideas here.

[`randi`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) can be used to get semi-random integers. Using that you can create a 2D matrix by duplicating the array and putting them together. Thus: generate a 30x1 column and duplicate it to a 30x2 column. All rows will have the same two entries, i.e. x=y.

Noise can be added to this by creating a 30x2 matrix of random numbers, use [`rand`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) for that and simply add that to the previously created matrix.

Check the documentation on [`svd`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) to see how the singular-value decomposition works, it's fairly straight-forward if you know your linear algebra.

Finally for plotting you can use various tools such as [`image`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html), [`imagesc`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html), [`plot`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), [`surf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) and [`scatter`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html), try them and see which works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example I made: https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/2d-points-randomly-near-line

```
%// Welcome to Saturn's MATLAB-Octave API.
%// Delete the sample code below these comments and write your own!'

x = 13 + 6.*rand(20,1);
y = x*0.7 + 0.5*rand(20,1);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y)

figure(1);
plot(x,y,'.');

%// Print plot as PNG with resultion of 60 pixels per inch
print("MyPNG.png", "-dpng", "-r60");
```